# Android Widget does not resize properly on different devices

Tags: android

I am working on a simple widget and I have problem with the layout and text resizing on similar, but different screens.
I have created a widget

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="path.to.class"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">
</appwidget-provider>
```

For now I am working on just the 5x1 layout. By testing this empirically I get very messy results:
[image]

These all are mandated by xxxhdpi resource file. What I do wrong and why the result is so inconsistent?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have your resizeMode set to horizontal which would explain why it is getting cut off vertically. I can't guarantee this will fix it but you should try updating resizeMode to be "both" and see if that fixes the issue.

So change

```
android:resizeMode="horizontal"
```

to be

```
android:resizeMode="both"
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo)

Comment: These are all 5x1 widgets, as I want them to be. I don't need the widget to be horizontally resizable. To some extend it seems that the issue is related to the back/home/recent buttons - if you have the navbar at the bottom, the cells for the widgets will have less vertical pixel to draw. On my Note 4 I don't have navbar as on the emulators there is. I will leave the question open a little more but it seems I will need to adjust the layout somehow

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand a little better now. Could you post the layout that you used for inside of the widget?